# Android WebView: cannot access site through VPN when using emulator

Tags: android, android-webview, vpn

I'm testing an application in the Eclipse emulator which loads a site through a WebView. My problem is that the site is only reachable when I'm connected to my job's VPN, I can access it from my PC's browser but not from the emulator. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    myWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://xxx");
}
}
```

When I tested with "http://google.com" it worked fine, the same when I used a random https site, but when I try to access the VPN site I got a "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error.
I'm already connected to the VPN, and also checked that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is before the `<application>` tag in the manifest. I've tested with Eclipse emulator and BlueStacks App Player, in both cases running the application and entering the URL into the emulators' browser, and got always the same result.
Is there any restrictions for this type of access in Android's emulators?
Thanks in advance, regards.

**UPDATE**

If I access the IP address from the emulator's browser, I can reach the site, but when I try to load it using `myWebView.loadUrl` got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out how to load my site, I put the IP address and the port instead of the URL that you can see in the "hosts" file. Also, I had to override the `onReceivedSslError` method of my CustomWebViewClient because I was getting a certification error when loading my page:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, android.webkit.SslErrorHandler handler, android.net.http.SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    };
```

Now loadUrl looks like this:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://IP:PORT/XXX");
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I hope to help me, I have webview app ,the site which I used blocked in some countries ,,Can I access it by use ur way